# Android XML setting z-Index

Tags: android, xml

Basically I have 2 linear layouts. One linear layout will expand or collapse when user clicked on the button. The other one will always shows at the top. Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNewsFeed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/lightred"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:text="News feed"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llNewsFeed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnNewsFeed"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/EventNewsFeedListview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:listSelector="#F6CECE" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/legendDiv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnNewsFeed"
            android:alpha=".75"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableEvent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:visibility="gone" >
                //Table Rows
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

So my legend div will be shown when user selected on the navigation drawer item and it has the opacity of 0.75. And my llNewsfeed will be expand or collapse when the btnNewsFeed onClick. The problem that I was having now is let's say when the legendDiv is shown, llNewsFeed was hide behind the legendDiv. I wonder is there any possible way to set the z-index for it? Because the llNewsFeed supposed to be in front of the legendDiv.

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bringToFront method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) like :

```
myView.bringToFront();
```

Also read this — Defining Z order of views. it may help.

Comment: Would you mind to provide me some code example? DO I have to set it programatically or thru XML file?

Comment: Programatically.
myView.bringToFront();

Answer (score 0):

Since API level 21 you can set the z-index with [View.setZ(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ%28float%29) or [View.setTranslationZ(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationZ%28float%29)